# missing values from spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dotdotdot, jquery-dotdotdot

```
let arr1 = [1, -2, 3, 4];
let arr2 = [8, 3, -8, 1];
function fun()
{
    console.log(arguments)
}
const fun1 = (...n) =>{
    console.log(n)
}
fun.call(...arr1, ...arr2)
```

output : [object Arguments] {
0: -2,
1: 3,
2: 4,
3: 8,
4: 3,
5: -8,
6: 1
}

```
fun1.call(...arr1,...arr2)
```

output : [-2, 3, 4, 8, 3, -8, 1]

arr1 and arr2 combined have 8 values but output is only 7 values why?
how to get all the values ?

Comment: Side note: `...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what `...` does. Rest and spread are primary syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've used [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call `fun`, and the first argument to `call` **isn't** an argument to pass to `fun`, it's the value to use as `this` during the call. So that first value doesn't show up in the arguments `fun` sees (it's the value of `this` instead, wrapped in an object wrapper if this is loose mode code).

There's no reason to use `fun.call` in your example, just:

```
fun(...arr1, ...arr2);
```

but if you needed to us `call` for some reason, you'd specify a different first argument (to use as `this` during the call):

```
fun.call(nullOrWhateverYouWantThisToBe, ...arr1, ...arr2);
```

(Side note: In modern JavaScript, there's almost never any reason to use the `arguments` pseudo-array. Use a rest parameter instead, which gives you a true array.)

With those changes:

```js
let arr1 = [1, -2, 3, 4];
let arr2 = [8, 3, -8, 1];
function fun(...args) {
    console.log(`args.length = ${args.length}`);
    console.log(`args:`, args);
}

fun(...arr1, ...arr2);
```